# Does Joe get captured in Shanghai because of revealing his intention to the future guy?

Tags: plot-explanation, looper

In *Looper* we learn that Joe is saving money so that he can travel to and live in Paris in the future.

When he reveals this information to the "guy from the future" he advises him to change his dream destination from Paris to Shanghai.

> "I am from the future, and I am telling you, go to Shanghai"

or something along these lines...

Later in the movie, we find out that Joe *does* indeed change his plan and goes to live in Shanghai. Then, 30 years later, he is captured by the people hiring the loopers and he was supposed to be sent back to the past for "his loop to be ended".

My question is: Is there any relation between the advice from the "future guy" and the capture taking place in Shanghai?
I mean: did the guy from the future try to change Joe's mind so that they will later know where to find him?

Comment: He wasn't arrested; the people who captured him were criminals.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's right. question is updated